# Listing rowindex as a letter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on a seat booking application for an assignment, and am having an issue.
I want to display the seats that are booked in a section of the site, for example "Booked: C13,C15, D12."
So far I have this section printing the row index and cell index. (for example, 0313, 0315, 0412) but want to set up some kind of translator or dictionary to change the row index to letters. I was looking at dictionarys but they didn't seem to be working.

```
var row = {
"A": 1, 
"B": 2, 
"C": 3, 
"D": 4, 
"E": 5
}
```

I am somewhat of a novice at Javascript, and I'm aware this is probably something very simple, but Google isn't giving me anything.

Comment: First use division along with `Math.floor()` to reduce your number down to its hundreds place, so you end up with `3` or `4`. Then use an Array instead of a plain Object, and use the number from before as an index into the Array.

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(65 + 5) === "E"`

Answer (score 0):

You want to go the other way. Since you're starting with an index, the index should be the key of the dictionary:

```
var row = {
    1: 'A',
    2: 'B',
    3: 'C',
    4: 'D',
    5: 'E'
};
```

Then you can use `row[rowIndex] + cellIndex` to combine them.

Comment: This is definitely getting further, although now it is printing [object Object] instead of the letter, must have to do with where in the code I am putting it?

Comment: You must be using `row` instead of `row[rowIndex]`.

Comment: I am using this code to get the row index:     var row=chairElem.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex; var row = { 0: "A", 1: "B", 2: "C", 3: "D", 4: "E" } and then this code to display the variables: .append(element='<div class="seatbooked"><img src="images/mine.gif" alt=mine/> <p>'+row+column+'</p></div>');  apologies for the formatting of this comment, when i replace +row+ with +row[rowIndex]+ it stops other functions on the site completely (a jQuery UI drag element)